# Plug-In development approach in C#.net

Tags: c#, plugins, architecture, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I am working on the plugin development, in which i have to make an architecture of the application in such a way if some other developer add some component in future then it should run without compiling the code it should read some configuration from config/xml file and load the specific plugin on the fly based on the object type. I have use the Activator to load the specific assembly.

```
 dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

I have made the class library for each component and load the assembly on the fly based on the configuration settings. I want to know if this is a valid approach ? Can I achieve this requirement in more correct way  because i also need to use the TPL(Task Process Library) to process the task in parallel in c#.net

Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft already has Managed Extension Framework MEF for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at one of the available solution for [IOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921087.aspx).

[MEF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx) is a nice one, but imply using decorations on your classes to define the exports/imports.

If you need a xml/json files configuration, you should look at
[Autofac](http://autofac.org/), [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) or [Castle](http://www.castleproject.org/).

And of course, all these solutions are compatible with the [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx). :)